# Replace string value with object values in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let formula = {width} + {height} + {weight} + {custom}
var custom = []
custom[25] = 2
custom[125] = 4
custom[225] = 5

{
    'width': 25,
    'height': 45,
    'weight': 95,
    'custom': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300}
}
```

I have above type of object, i want to replace the formula variables with my above object values. I want to replace my formula value with the object values. Also my bject has one kyw which has name like "custom" that key is not complusory in some of object it's available and some of it's not. Now I want to replace the custom object with {custom} key.

I want like this

```
1) 25 + 45 + 95 + 100
2) 25 + 45 + 95 + 200
4) 25 + 45 + 95 + 300
```

I tried this

```
custom.forEach((value, i) => {
    let output = formula.replace(/{(\w+?)}/g, (m, c) => myobject[c]);
});
```

**Possible types formula**

```
let formula1 = {width} + {height} + {weight} - {custom}
let formula2 = {width} * {height} - {weight}
let formula3 = {width} * {height} - {weight} * {custom}
```

Comment: since `let formula = {width} + {height} + {weight} + {custom}` is invalid javascript, its difficult to know what you want to do with `formula` - have you heard of template literals in javascript? almost looks like you're trying to re-invent those

Comment: here formula is my string, I want to replace my object variable values in my formula and later I use javascript eval function for calculate the formula result

Comment: What is the issue with your code? Can you please transform the example into a JavaScript snippet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t7cv6uze/1/  here as you can check for custom it replace it with object, I want there my custom object value

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i added fiddle

Comment: So you want to actually replace one string containing placeholders with three lines with values?

Comment: yes exactly like that

Comment: Ok, you can't use a single `.replace` here. You need to do something like shown below. Please check and accept if it works for you, or provide more details. +1 to offset hater's downvote.

Comment: I don't want like this ${obj.width} + ${obj.height} + ${obj.weight} because I have more than 100 keys in that object so.

Comment: `here formula is my string` no it isn't, it's an invalid javascript construct - how can anyone help if you start with invalid syntax in your code?

Comment: what do the keys/values in `custom` array have to do with the result? what is `profilePriceData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using for template literals is incorrect, there is also no need for regex in a problem like this.

This snippet does what you are looking for.

```js
let obj = {
    'width': 25,
    'height': 45,
    'weight': 95,
    'custom': {
        0: 100,
        1: 200,
        2: 300
    }
}

let operatorList = prompt("Enter the 3 operators you would like to use. eg '++-'").split("").slice(0, 3) // The string used to join the items values from the object

// Iterate over each key of 'obj.custom'
for (let key in obj.custom) {
    let valuesArray = []

    // Iterate through each value of 'obj'
    for (let value of Object.values(obj)) {

        // Make sure that the value is a number or a string
        if (typeof value === "object") continue;

        // Append the value to the 'valuesArray'
        valuesArray.push(value)
    }

    valuesArray.push(obj.custom[key]) // Add the correct value from the `obj.custom` object

    let valuesAndOperators = []
    let listClone = Array.from(operatorList) // Create a clone of the list of operators

    for (let value of valuesArray) {
        valuesAndOperators.push(value) // Add values to new array
        valuesAndOperators.push(listClone.shift()) // Add operators between values
    }

    console.log(`${parseInt(key) + 1}) ${valuesAndOperators.join(" ")}`)
}
```

Comment: I don't want like this ${obj.width} + ${obj.height} + ${obj.weight} because I have more than 100 keys in that object so.

Comment: Does each key of the object need to be part of the sum? @user8989878

Comment: yes each are part of the sum

Comment: Every key apart from custom? Make sure to add this detail to your post, I will edit my answer. @user8989878

Comment: Yes every key apart from custom should be replace need to be add each custom object value in my final formula

Comment: @user8989878 This should work irrespective of object size.

Comment: Thea above code is working but the one issue is in ${valuesArray.join(" + ")}` u joined it using plus, in my string it can be anything like "/, *" how to do this?

Comment: @user8989878 You can just replace the string with, whatever character(s)  you want to join the items in the array with. You could even set this string to a variable, and change its value programmatically.

Comment: i am not getting it can u please add in your answer

Comment: @user8989878 All of this should have been specified in your post.

Comment: Can u please check my edited post

Comment: @user8989878 You should now be able to enter the operators you want to use.